# How do I use Ninject to inject AutoMapper Mapper in place of IMapper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, automapper

I get this injector error

Error activating IConfigurationProvider
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
 3) Injection of dependency IConfigurationProvider into parameter configurationProvider of constructor of type Mapper
 2) Injection of dependency IMapper into parameter mapper of constructor of type MyController
 1) Request for MyController

My global asx

```
Mapper.Initialize(c => c.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());
```

My mapping profile

```
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Obj, ObjBO>().ReverseMap();
    }
    }
```

My Controller

```
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public MyController(IMapper mapper)
    {

        _mapper = mapper;
    }
```

Trying to use the mapper like this

```
        IEnumerable<ObjBO> list = _repo.GetObjs();
        IEnumerable <Obj> mappedList= _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Obj>>(list);
```

I tried adding this to NinjectWebCommons

```
                private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
                {
                   kernel.Bind<IMapper>().To<Mapper>().InRequestScope();
                }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoMapper 4.2 and Ninject 3.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233989/automapper-4-2-and-ninject-3-2)

Answer (score 5):

Your bindings are configured to construct a new instance of Mapper for each request, but you've configured a static Mapper.  Here's a configuration similar to one I'm using.

```
kernel.Bind<IMapper>()
    .ToMethod(context =>
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
            // tell automapper to use ninject when creating value converters and resolvers
            cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(t => kernel.Get(t));
        });
        return config.CreateMapper();
    }).InSingletonScope();
```

You can then remove your static configuration

```
Mapper.Initialize(c => c.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());
```